# C# DataGridView empty when using concrete type, displays data when using anonymous type

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, .net-4.0

I'm trying to display using a DataGridView and I'm getting some strange results.

When I set the data source with an anonymous type like so:

```
var displayList = CreateAnAnonymousBindingList(new { prop1 = string. Empty ...etc... } );
displayList.AllowNew = true; //The property in the DataGridView is set in the designer

var list = from someEntity in entities.EntityGroup //I want some of the fields from each entity
           select new { prop1 = someEntity.prop1...etc...};

foreach(item in list)
{
   displayList.add(item);
}

form.dataGridView.DataSource = displayList;
```

The data I want is displayed, but I cannot add new items, there is an exception caused by the anonymous type. This, I know, is because it is an anonymous type and has no constructors.

The problem is, when I create a concrete class using the same types, even names as the anonymous type, create a BindingList (simply by new BindingList()) and add items to it like:

```
BindingList<ClassName> displayList = new BindingList<ClassName>();
displayList.AllowNew = true;

var list = from someEntity in entities.EntityGroup
          select someEntity;

foreach(var item in list)
{
   ClassName temp = new ClassName();
   /* Assign all the properties I want*/
   displayList.Add(temp);
}

form.dataGridView.DataSource = displayList;
```

Nothing is displayed, even though the list has items in it, and the data source is set to the list. I cannot work out why this is happening, maybe I'm overlooking something really, really simple, but I cannot see where the issue is coming from.

Any help would be fantastic.

Comment: Try to set GridView.DataMember = your class name.

Comment: Is the AutoGenerateColumns-Property set to `true` ?

Comment: Do you really have properties in "ClassName" class? A simple public field won't work.

Comment: @xeondev thanks, I'd been using public fields in a barebones class, changed it to actual properties and it fixed it. Thanks

Comment: @ThomasG Added as an answer, please accept it if works for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your class to use properties and datagridview will display the list.

```
class ClassName
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```